# Not able to find Windows Presentation Foundation in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: wpf, visual-studio

I wanted to create WPF project using visual studio 2022. I am not able to find the project template. What package should I use?

Comment: Make sure the ".NET desktop development" component is installed (see VS installer "Workload" tab).

Comment: Thanks @BionicCode installing ".NET desktop development" worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing .NET desktop development worked for me.

Comment: Hi Bhushan Jagtap, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider accepting it as the answer to change its status to Answered. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)